# SQLite Triggers Error on launching android apps

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I'm trying to create an app that using triggers on its DB. Whenever i try to run it on Android Studio the apps is working well and no error in the code. But when I try to run it on MEmu or a Lollipop mobile phone its show me some error message. I've tried to fix it, but now there is this message when i tried to launch it after some fixing.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dexpensemanager/com.dexpensemanager.Home}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: qualified table names are not allowed on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements within triggers (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_income  AFTER INSERT  ON TRANS FOR  EACH  ROW  WHEN  TRANS.type= income  AND  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month')  BEGIN  insert into SUMTRANS.income  SELECT SUM(income) FROM TRANS.amount  END;
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:169)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:967)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: qualified table names are not allowed on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements within triggers (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_income  AFTER INSERT  ON TRANS FOR  EACH  ROW  WHEN  TRANS.type= income  AND  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month')  BEGIN  insert into SUMTRANS.income  SELECT SUM(income) FROM TRANS.amount  END;
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
>       at com.example.connectionDB.DBnTrigger.onCreate(DBnTrigger.java:45)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>       at com.example.connectionDB.DBnTrigger.getLastIncome(DBnTrigger.java:459)
>       at com.dexpensemanager.Home.onCreate(Home.java:61)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>       ... 10 more

and here's the code for my triggers i take it from  [create trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) refference

```
public String insincTrigger() {
    String insinc = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_income "
            + " AFTER INSERT "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_TABLE
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " WHEN "
            + " TRANS.type= income "
            + " AND  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " insert into SUMTRANS.income "
            + " SELECT SUM(income) FROM TRANS.amount "
            + " END; ";

    return insinc;
}

public String insexpTrigger(){
    String insexp = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_expense "
            + " AFTER INSERT "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_TABLE
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " WHEN "
            + " TRANS.type= expense "
            + " WHERE  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " insert into SUMTRANS.expense "
            + " SELECT SUM(expense) FROM TRANS.amount "
            + " END; ";
    return insexp;
}

public String upincTrigger(){
    String upinc = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists usumcalc_income "
            + " AFTER UPDATE "
            + " OF [amount] "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_TABLE
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " WHEN "
            + " TRANS.type= income "
            + " WHERE  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " UPDATE OR REPLACE "+TRANSACTION_SUM
            + " SET [income] = SELECT SUM(income) from TRANS.amount "
            + " END; ";
    return upinc;
}

public String upexpTrigger() {
    String upexp = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists usumcalc_expense "
            + " AFTER UPDATE "
            + " OF [amount] "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_TABLE
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " WHEN "
            + " TRANS.type= expense "
            + " WHERE  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " UPDATE OR REPLACE "+TRANSACTION_SUM
            + " SET [expense] = SELECT SUM(expense) from TRANS.amount "
            + " END; ";
    return upexp;
}

public String delTrigger(){
    String del = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_delete "
            + " AFTER DELETE "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_TABLE
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " WHEN "
            + " TRANS.type = income AND expense "
            + " WHERE  strftime ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " DELETE FROM "+TRANSACTION_SUM
            + " WHERE = SELECT SUM(income AND expense) from TRANS.amount "
            + " END; ";
    return del;
}

public String instimeTrigger(){
    String instime = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_instime "
            + " AFTER INSERT "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_SUM
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " insert into SUMTRANS.month "
            + " VALUES ('%Y'-'%m','now','start of month') "
            + " END;";
    return instime;
}

public String deltimeTrigger(){
    String deltime = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists sumcalc_instime "
            + " AFTER DELETE "
            + " ON "+TRANSACTION_SUM
            + " FOR  EACH  ROW "
            + " BEGIN "
            + " DELETE FROM SUMTRANS.month "
            + " END; ";
    return deltime;
}
```

could someone tell me what should i do?

THANKS.

Comment: in this DB there 2 tables Transaction_table and sumtrans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception stack is clearly stating the problem:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: qualified table names are not allowed on
INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements within triggers (code 1)
```

From the very linked [SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) in your question (emphasis mine):

> Syntax Restrictions On UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT Statements Within Triggers
>
> The UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT statements within triggers do not support the full syntax for UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT statements. The following restrictions apply:
>
> - The name of the table to be modified in an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT
>     statement must be an unqualified table name. In other words, ***one must
>     use just "tablename" not "database.tablename" when specifying the
>     table. The table to be modified must exist in the same database as
>     the table or view to which the trigger is attached.***
> - The "INSERT INTO table DEFAULT VALUES" form of the INSERT statement
>     is not supported.
> - The INDEXED BY and NOT INDEXED clauses are not supported for UPDATE
>     and DELETE statements.
> - The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses on UPDATE and DELETE statements are
>     not supported. ORDER BY and LIMIT are not normally supported for
>     UPDATE or DELETE in any context but can be enabled for top-level
>     statements using the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time
>     option. However, that compile-time option only applies to top-level
>     UPDATE and DELETE statements, not UPDATE and DELETE statements within
>     triggers.
> - Common table expression are not supported for statements inside of
>     triggers.

I suppose `SUMTRANS` in statement `insert into SUMTRANS.expense` is the database name. As per the docs, that's not supported.

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow i thought its supported . i suppose not all in the refference is valid then thanks anyway